# Pass a data variable to encrypt/decrypt in line command OpenSSL using C

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography

What I am trying to do is to use C programming to make calls to OpenSSL to encrypt and decrypt sensitive data. So far **I have been using files** containing both the keys and the data. But files are, I think, **a potential security problem** which I'd like to avoid.

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey publicKey.pem -pubin -in data.txt -out enc.txt

openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privateKey.pem -in enc.txt -out decrypt.txt
```

These are the commonly used commands to RSA encrypt/decrypt a file. Let's say that `data.txt`contains the following text :

`Hello World`

Is there any way *to pass directly the string* `Hello World`*to the command line* instead of using a file ?

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey publicKey.pem -pubin "Hello World" -out enc.txt
```

This would be used, in C, like this :

```
char cmd[200] = "";
char data [50] = " \"Hello World\" ";

strcpy(cmd,    CMD_ACCESS_OPENSSL); // path to access utility
strcat(cmd,    "rsautl -encrypt -inkey publicKey.pem -pubin");
strcat(cmd,    data);
strcat(cmd,    "-out enc.txt");

if (system(cmd) != 0)
    exit 1; // If failed exit
```

Comment: Why not use the OpenSSL library instead of the OpenSSL command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the openssl command line tool, you can provide the data to be encrypted on stdin by omitting the `-in`-parameter, i.e.:

```
echo -n "Hello World" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey publicKey.pem -pubin -out enc.txt
```

Embedding this into C-Code is a bit more tedious, since you have to create a pipe and write to it (untested!):

```
char cmd[200] = "";

strcpy(cmd,    CMD_ACCESS_OPENSSL); // path to access utility
strcat(cmd,    "rsautl -encrypt -inkey publicKey.pem -pubin ");
strcat(cmd,    "-out enc.txt");

FILE *p = popen(cmd, "w");

if (p != NULL) {
    fprintf(p, "Hello World!");
    pclose(p);
} else {
    perror("popen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

But a more clean approach with C is to use the openssl c api for encrypting your data, visit the [OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Main_Page) for start.

Comment: Write into stdin in C, because by default OpenSSL reads stdin to get the data to encrypt. Is that it ? Also, the API you are refering to is `libssl` library ?

Comment: @Badda Thats correct. I am referring to the `libcrypto`-library, which is a part of openssl.

Comment: Well, these two solutions are both very interesting. Thanks a lot